# How to configure adf rich faces version 11.1.2.2.0 in MyEclipse

Tags: jar, configuration, oracle-adf, web.xml, myeclipse

I am unable to configure adf-rich faces in MyEClipse IDE. How to Configure adf-rich faces of jars, web.xml, config files in a Project.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try using jdeveloper IDE for developing adf based project?

[Oracle JDeveloper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/overview/index.html)

or you can view the below link on how to configure eclipse with adf comp

Comment: I am familiar with My-eclipse IDE. All my projects are present run on My-eclipse. Help me folks. Need configuration files (web.xml and config.xml ) files.

Answer (score 1):

How about installing OEPE  aka Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse [Eclipse Based Enterprise Application Development](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/overview/index.html)
Do a sample and look at the generated configuration files.

Comment: Hello Timo, I want configuration in MyClipse (8.x + ) IDE not in Eclipse. I search in oracle site, but there is no details in that site how to configure adf-rich in MyEclipse IDE.

Comment: Obviously Oracle doesn't support this directly. This is the reason why I suggested to install the OEPE to find out how it's done there.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the OEPE plugins into an existing Eclipse installation. See information [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/index.html)

Comment: Hi, I am using MyEclipse IDE, Eclipse is too old. Can you tell me how to configure / run adf-rich in MyEclipse IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you are trying to achieve.
If you just want the libraries for ADF Faces included inside your project then the simplest would probably be to download the ADF Faces components demo and open the WAR in MyEclipse.
http://content.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/download/index.html

If you also want visual development capabilities for ADF Faces you can try installing the OEPE plugins into your myEclipse.
See the repositories at the end of this page: [Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse (12.1.1.2.1)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/index.html)